# What will happen human with Shinigami powers died while they are in human form?

Tags: bleach

As a human, death is inevitable, even for healthiest person in the world (ageing cannot be stopped). When a normal human die, their soul chain is cut. However, things are different those with unactivated shinigami power who obtain shinigami power while they are still alive through unnatural means, [like Ichigo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPEwQdlKpr4&t=20m15s). The question that many of us has been wondering is that what would happen if human with in-born Shinigami power (activated), die while they are in human form.

Comment: With Ginjo showing up again in the manga, I'll vote re-open after Kubo-sensei explains why he can be there despite being implied as dead when Ichigo asked Gotei 13 for his body at the end of Fullbringer arc.

Comment: Thank you.. You are my saviour.. You are reviewing to old unwanted post.. i will vote you as a mod if i can. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go with other people who died in Bleach, the moment they died, their soul came out of their body. Unlike people who only half-dead, like Inoue when she was assaulted by his brother who has turned into a hollow, a dead people have his chain of fate separated from his body, which means he won't be able to return to his body. His body would still have the chain and if let on his own, the chain would start to erode until when it eroded completely, he turned into a hollow.

Shinigami is a soul, as can be seen during the flashback of Rukia and Renji's past. Both was resident of Rukongai, the residential district. And it was shown during Chad's awakening that a soul that is sent to Soul Society is sent to the Rukongai area. This suggests that Rukia and Renji was a human too before they starts entering the Shinigami academy and turned into one.

Now, since Ichigo is already a Shinigami, and a Shinigami is a soul, then if he died he would just simply turned into a Shinigami, except that he won't be able to return to his body. He can of course enter a gigai shaped just like his body.

Comment: will he lose his memory?

Comment: No. The kid that Chad saved didn't lost his memory.

Comment: can you explain more on when ichigo get first get his hollow stuff in urahara base?